# File won't get deployed? (HardhatError: HH700: Artifact not found.)

Tags: solidity

I'm following this tutorial here: https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/hello-world-smart-contract-fullstack/ and I'm stuck with this error message:
`HardhatError: HH700: Artifact for contract "HelloWorld" not found.`

From what I found on the forums it seems to be a naming problem but the name for the contract & what is being deployed is the same:

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.3;


contract HelloWorld {

   
   event UpdatedMessages(string oldStr, string newStr);

   string public message;

   constructor(string memory initMessage) {


      message = initMessage;
   }


   function update(string memory newMessage) public {
      string memory oldMsg = message;
      message = newMessage;
      emit UpdatedMessages(oldMsg, newMessage);
   }
}
```

and this is the deploy.js file:

```
async function main() {
  const HelloWorld = await ethers.getContractFactory("HelloWorld")

  // Start deployment, returning a promise that resolves to a contract object
  const hello_world = await HelloWorld.deploy("Hello World!")
  console.log("Contract deployed to address:", hello_world.address)
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error)
    process.exit(1)
  })
```

When I compile it just says "Nothing to compile" and running this command: `npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network ropsten` given mentioned HH700 error.
Can anyone please help?

Comment: does the artifact really exist? can you check/share your file tree

Comment: thanks for your reply. I actually ended up deleting it on my Windows10 and doing the hardhat tutorial (https://hardhat.org/tutorial/deploying-to-a-live-network.html) on a VM with Ubuntu 20.04 and it's working great. 
I probably should be getting a MBP as I plan to spend more time with Solidity development?

Comment: hmu if you face it again. And no, you don't *need* a MBP for development. Ubuntu will serve you just fine

Comment: hey @keser how you doing? do you know how this works? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71624208/parsing-error-when-compiling-with-solidity

Answer (score 1):

Could be that you are missing the “npx hardhat compile” before the test. The artifacts are created when you compile.

Answer (score 0):

const hello_world = await HelloWorld.deploy("Hello World!")
should be
const hello_world = await deploy("HelloWorld!")