# Parsing error when compiling with Solidity

Tags: compilation, solidity

I'm trying to compile 2 chainlink references in Solidity with Brownie:

```
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/vendor/SafeMathChainlink.sol";
```

For which I'm using the `brownie-config.yaml` file with the following content:

```
dependencies:
# - <organization/repo>@<version>
- smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - '@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1'
```

when I compile with `brownie compile` I get this error, looks like the source file is using a different Solidity version:

```
Brownie v1.18.1 - Python development framework for Ethereum

Compiling contracts...
  Solc version: 0.8.13
  Optimizer: Enabled  Runs: 200
  EVM Version: Istanbul
CompilerError: solc returned the following errors:

ParserError: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.8.13+commit.abaa5c0e.Linux.g++) - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
```

What can I do here? My Solidity file is already set to `pragma solidity >=0.6.6 <0.9.0;`
Any help greatly is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your imported files do not match your version pragma. You are importing

`chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";`

which has the version:

`pragma solidity ^0.6.0;`

And it will not compile with compilers starting `0.7.0`. Try using a newer chainlink library version or downgrade your solidity file to

`pragma solidity >=0.6.0 <0.9.0;`